# Dynamic Routing and fetching single item from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, routes, next.js

Inside my data.js I have a 'product' array with the values 'name' and 'path' in it.
The page address is referred to as 'path'

```
data.js

export const product = [{name:Processor,      path:processor},
                        {name:Graphics Card,  path:graphics-card}]
```

My Index page

```
index.js
-------------

import { product } from "data";

export default function Builder({ children }) {
return(
<>
<Navbar>
{product.map((item) => (
           <li key={item.path}>
             <Link href={`/products/${item.path}`} >
               <a><span >{item.name}</span></a>
             </Link>
          </li>
        ))})
</Navbar>
{children}
</>

}
```

[product] is dynamically created page.

My folder structure

> data.js
> index.js
> products/ 
>  [product].js

```
[product.js]
------------

import Builder from "./index"

export default function Product() {
  return (
    <>
    <Builder>

        //I need to display 'product-name' here.

    </Builder>
    </>
  )
}
```

When I use 'router.query' I only see 'product-path'. Instead, each page must display the relevant 'product-name.'

I'm new to nextjs, so if someone can assist me in finding a solution, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your object values in your `product.js` needs to be strings ie: `"Graphics Card"` instead of `Graphics Card`.

Normally we make new requests for data based on the dynamic URL segments. So in this case it could look something like this for example in your `product.js`.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Builder from './index';
import { product } from 'data.js';

export default function Product() {
  const [currentProduct, setCurrentProduct] = useState('');
  const router = useRouter();
  const { path } = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    const item = product.filter((item) => item.path === path);
    setCurrentProduct(item[0].name);
  }, []);

  return <Builder>{currentProduct}</Builder>;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message.  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')                                                                  {productItem[0].name}                                                                               
It happens when I reload the page.

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly, try the new implementation.